# Create a new column with values based on conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would need to create a column with values based on a third column. Example:

```
df <- data.frame(antibodies = c("positive","positive","positive","positive",
                            "negative","negative","negative","negative",
                            "negative","positive","positive","negative"),
             AA = c(123, 345, 7567, 234, 8679, 890, 
                    812, 435345, 567, 568, 786, 678),
             stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to create a new column named `df$BB`, to make this column I want the following 2 conditions:

- If antibodies is positive then BB= AA+2
- If antibodies is negative then BB== AA

How can I express this in R?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an attempt:

```
# Base R
df$BB <- ifelse(df$antibodies == "positive", df$AA + 2, df$AA)

# Dplyr
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(BB = if_else(antibodies == "positive", AA + 2, AA))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `within`.

```
df <- within(df, {
  BB <- AA
  BB[antibodies == "positive"] <- BB + 2
})
df
#    antibodies     AA     BB
# 1    positive    123    125
# 2    positive    345    347
# 3    positive   7567   7569
# 4    positive    234    236
# 5    negative   8679   8679
# 6    negative    890    890
# 7    negative    812    812
# 8    negative 435345 435345
# 9    negative    567    567
# 10   positive    568    570
# 11   positive    786    788
# 12   negative    678    678
```

Comment: I used `with`, you used `within`. Do you know if there is a big difference between those two?

Comment: @MartinGal Basically `within` copies the entire data frame, whereas `with` just references to it. Type `?within`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R`'s `ifelse`-function:

```r
df$BB <- ifelse(df$antibodies=="positive", df$AA + 2, df$AA)
```

or combined with `with`

```r
df$BB <- with(df, ifelse(antibodies=="positive", AA + 2, AA))
```

returns

```r
   antibodies     AA     BB
1    positive    123    125
2    positive    345    347
3    positive   7567   7569
4    positive    234    236
5    negative   8679   8679
6    negative    890    890
7    negative    812    812
8    negative 435345 435345
9    negative    567    567
10   positive    568    570
11   positive    786    788
12   negative    678    678
```

Another solution could be

```r
df$BB <- as.numeric(df$antibodies == "positive") * 2 + df$AA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a data.table solution for the problem.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, BB := ifelse(antibodies == "positive", AA + 2, AA)]
```